# MirrorSourceConnector: override consumer key.serializer property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to run MirrorSourceConnector from a Topic in cluster A to cluster B.
After creating the connector and consuming first message I noticed that mirrored topic key and value is always serialized as a ByteArray. Which in case of a key is a bit of a problem when doing the transformations with a custom class.

After checking MirrorSourceConfig class in github I found out that with source.admin. and target.admin I could basically add consumer and producer properties. But seems it does not make any different (in logs I could still see that ByteArray serializer is being used).

My connector config looks like that:

```
{"target.cluster.status.storage.replication.factor": "-1",
 "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
 "auto.create.mirror.topics.enable": true,
 "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor": "1",
 "replication.factor": "1",
 "sync.topic.acls.enabled": "false",
 "topics": "test-topic",
 "target.cluster.config.storage.replication.factor": "-1",
 "source.cluster.alias": "source-cluster-dev",
 "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "source-cluster-dev:9092",
 "target.cluster.offset.storage.replication.factor": "-1",
 "target.cluster.alias": "target-cluster-dev",
 "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
 "header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "name": "test-mirror-connector",
 "source.admin.key.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
 "source.admin.value.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
 "target.admin.key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
 "target.admin.value.serializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
 "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "target-cluster-dev:9092"}
```

Is there a way to override Consumer and Producer Ser/De-serialization properties or any other way to make mirror topic to be exactly the same as a source topic? In the meaning of seralization.

Comment: "make mirror topic to be exactly the same as a source topic" - That is what ByteArraySerializer does... It is just a passthrough and should not affect your downstream consumer deserializers. Also, the converters are what decide the serializers that are used, and you shouldn't (cant?) override underlying client serializer settings

Comment: Thank for reply I think I nearly understand it. But just to get a full picture here. If I have:

Original topic with messages serialized --> key = String, value = Byte Array.

Then I'm Mirroring it with --> key = StringConverter, value = ByteArrayConverter
Should I be able to consume the mirrored topic with Consumer that uses String deserializer for key and ByteArray for value?

Comment: Like I said, mirror only as bytes, so use byte converter for everything. Consumers in the remote cluster can then, yes, use whatever deserializer they wish